# Dynamic Pivot SQL Column Data to Header

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-pivot

I would like to transpose the following table so that the first column (tabLabel) becomes the header. I need to do this dynamically, because the number of rows is unknown. I've seen posts on dynamic pivots, but I don't fully understand how this would be done.

```
tabLabel            documentId  recipientId     Date    value
Street Address          1           1           NULL    123 mockingbird lane
City                    1           1           NULL    city
Patient Phone           1           1           NULL    999-999-9999
Responsible Phone       1           1           NULL    999-999-9999
Gross Income            1           1           NULL    999
Monthly Mortgage/Rent   1           1           NULL    100
Monthly Auto            1           1           NULL    200
```

Final version:

```
Street Address         City   Patient Phone   Responsible Phone   Gross Income  Monthly Mortage/Rent   Monthly Auto   documentId   recipientId   Date
123 mockingbird lane   city   999-999-9999    999-999-9999        999           100                    200            1             1            NULL
```

Select Query on Original Table:

```
SELECT [tabLabel]
  ,[documentId]
  ,[recipientId]
  ,[Date]
  ,[value]
  FROM [zDocusign_Document_Tab_Fields]
```

Comment: Can you do it in your code?  It'd be a lot easier to read.

Comment: @user2023861 do you mean to insert my create table or an insert statement?

Comment: I mean, if you're reading this data into some application, you can pivot the data there.  I know that doing this in C# would be a lot easier than what I saw when I googled "sql server dynamic pivot"

Comment: @user2023861 no, I can't really do that. I only have access to sql statements for this data.

Comment: you have to show some kind of query.. it's important to know if you're filtering the data because the filter in a pivot query has to go in a certain place

Comment: @JamieD77 I am not filtering it. I edited to include a select statement for the original table. That's really all there is to it. The data coming in has no specifications that have to be handled in SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dynamic sql

```
-- Build colums
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT  @cols = STUFF((
    SELECT  DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME([tabLabel])
    FROM    zDocusign_Document_Tab_Fields
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
-- Selecting as FOR XML PATH will give you a string value with all of the fields combined
-- separated by comma.  Stuff simply removes the first comma.
-- Quotename wraps the [tabLabel] value in brackets to allow for spaces in column name
-- You end up with
-- [City],[Gross Income],[Monthly Auto],[Monthly Mortgage/Rent],[Patient Phone],[Responsible Phone],[Street Address]

-- Build sql
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET     @sql = N'
    SELECT  ' + @cols +' 
    FROM    zDocusign_Document_Tab_Fields
    PIVOT   (
        MAX([value])
        FOR [tabLabel] IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) p
'

-- Execute Sql
EXEC(@sql)
```